# pandas groupby apply on multiple columns to generate a new column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, pandas-apply

I like to generate a new column in pandas dataframe using groupby-apply.

For example, I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4],'B':['A','B','A','B'],'C':[0,0,1,1]})
```

and try to generate a new column 'D' by groupby-apply.

This works:

```
df = df.assign(D=df.groupby('B').C.apply(lambda x: x - x.mean()))
```

as (I think) it returns a series with the same index with the dataframe:

```
In [4]: df.groupby('B').C.apply(lambda x: x - x.mean())
Out[4]:
0   -0.5
1   -0.5
2    0.5
3    0.5
Name: C, dtype: float64
```

But if I try to generate a new column using multiple columns, I cannot assign it directly to a new column. So this doesn't work:

```
 df.assign(D=df.groupby('B').apply(lambda x: x.A - x.C.mean()))
```

returning

```
TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index
```

and in fact, the groupby-apply returns:

```
In [8]: df.groupby('B').apply(lambda x: x.A - x.C.mean())
Out[8]:
B
A  0    0.5
   2    2.5
B  1    1.5
   3    3.5
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

I could do

```
df.groupby('B').apply(lambda x: x.A - x.C.mean()).reset_index(level=0,drop=True))
```

but it seems verbose and I am not sure if this will work as expected always.

So my question is: (i) when does pandas groupby-apply return a like-indexed series vs a multi-index series? (ii) is there a better way to assign a new column by groupby-apply to multiple columns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's use `group_keys=False` in the groupby

```
df.assign(D=df.groupby('B', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.A - x.C.mean()))
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C    D
0  1  A  0  0.5
1  2  B  0  1.5
2  3  A  1  2.5
3  4  B  1  3.5
```

Comment: This directly answers my question.

Comment: Be aware that this solution only works if the `.apply()` method returns a series with the same number of rows as the data frame your are assigning to. Otherwise the index of the returned series and the data frame will not match.

Comment: @petrovski Thanks for pointing that out, I was wondering how something like that would possibly work

Answer (score 5):

For this case I do not think include the column A in apply is necessary, we can use `transform`

```
df.A-df.groupby('B').C.transform('mean')
Out[272]: 
0    0.5
1    1.5
2    2.5
3    3.5
dtype: float64
```

And you can assign it back

```
df['diff']= df.A-df.groupby('B').C.transform('mean')
df
Out[274]: 
   A  B  C  diff
0  1  A  0   0.5
1  2  B  0   1.5
2  3  A  1   2.5
3  4  B  1   3.5
```