# Pandas-GroupBy-apply function to create a new column based on calculation on two existing column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, lambda, apply

[image]

I trying to achieve the same with this line of code:

```
df['Math/Physic']=df.groupby(['Rank'],sort=False).apply(lambda x:x['Maths']/x['Physics'])--->doesn't work
```

I am getting this below error:

```
TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index
```

This code below work though. It looks like , the code above not able to fetch value from those columns:

```
df['Math/Physic']=df.groupby(['Rank'],sort=False).apply(lambda x:10/2])--->works fine
```

I have tried different variations but not able to get this working. Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: please provide your input as reproducible code or text (not images!)

Comment: Try this : `df['Math/Physic']=df.groupby(['Rank'],sort=False).apply(lambda x:x['Maths']/x['Physics'], axis=1)`

Comment: I am getting TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'. 
Tried out a solution from :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47227280/pandas-groupby-apply-on-multiple-columns-to-generate-a-new-column
df_new=df.assign(Math/Physic=df.groupby('Rank',group_keys=False).apply(lambda x:x['Maths']/x['Physics']))--->work now but had to assign the result to new dataFrame. new column show up on df_new.head() or df_new.columns

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.